# Dragging from Windows Explorer to VSCode, to move a file?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, windows-explorer

Currently, dragging the file to Tree View always copies it.

Im trying to organize a fast- and smooth- to-use VSC setup which will allow to not/minimally use Windows Explorer, and need the functionality for drag-moving files from WE, specifically for moving internet shortcuts that are created: from browser, on desktop.

It would be great to make Firefox create the shortcuts if the address are dragged to VSC's File Explorer, but its less universal addition and i guess: and/or harder.

Is there a way how i can achieve this?
Im not-deep in VSC internals/extensions, and these languages. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is rather a feature request for vscode than a Q&A style question.

Comment: @MikeLischke . Its a question about a way of adding it, Seems that i didn't write it directly, but sorry but its obvious -- what im asking for .

Comment: If this is a feature request for VS Code, it would be better to post it over at their [Github page](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues). If this is a request for someone to create an extension for you, then that would be off-topic here.

Comment: @GinoMempin . I don't ask for more than anyone have/know . A type of the required edit (extension / existing modding API / VSC rebuild from source / ..), [| and related handles ] is already enough . Less terms and more details are just better .